# Not working XOR checksum algorithm in C++

Tags: c++, arduino, checksum, xor

I get messed up with a simple XOR-checksum calculated on an cstring char array for a telegram.

The strange thing is: the decoding of the checksum works. It is for an Arduino application sending a telegram from one Arduino to another.

This is the telegram to be sent including a correct checksum after the *:

> $GPS,52.534015,3.9,13.496394,2.5,0.053,0,44.6,6.2*65

You look right: It is like a NEMEA message.

So here is the code for the checksum calculation

```
MessageStr.toCharArray(MessageBuffer, MessageStr.length()); //Arduino String Class
for (int x = 1; x < (sizeof(MessageBuffer)/sizeof(MessageBuffer[0])); x++)
{
    if (MessageBuffer[x] == '*')
    {
        Serial.println();
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        MesChecksum ^= MessageBuffer[x]; //XOR the Message data...
    }
}
MessageStr += MesChecksum;
Serial.println(MessageStr);
```

It calculates even to big checksums.

- 102 instead 62
- 103 instead 67

I checked the checksum with this online tool:
[NEMEA checksum calc](http://www.hhhh.org/wiml/proj/nmeaxor.html)

On the other side I use a similar code I already used for parsing the NEMEA message:

```
boolean TelegramCheckChecksum(char* Message, int MessageLength)
{
    byte checksumReceived = 0, checksum = 0;
    for (int x = 1; x < MessageLength; x++)
    {
        if (Message[x] == '*') //Checksum starts with '*'
        {
            checksumReceived = strtol(&Message[x + 1], NULL, 16); //Parsing received checksum... |strtol parsing string to integer
            break; //Exit for and continue with next if
        }
        else
        {
            checksum ^= Message[x]; //XOR the received data...
        }
    }
    if (checksum == checksumReceived)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I tried really everything. Even checking by hand bitwise. Without any success.

Comment: Why are you starting your for loops at the index 1?

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct for calculating the checksum, however you are not converting the number to hex when adding it to the message.
Note that 102 in decimal is 62 in hex.

To convert a number to a hex string using the standard library, you can use a `stringstream`

```
std::stringstream stream;
stream << std::hex << MesChecksum;
std::string result( stream.str() );
```

Using the Arduino String class you can do something like this (I think - I can't test it):

```
MessageStr += String(MesCheckSum, HEX);
```